# Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld failed

Tags: mysql, linux, permissions, terminal, uninstallation

Basically, when i want to sop mysql server service :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

i'm getting this error message:

```
[FAIL] Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld failed!
```

After some research to solve this i followed this to-do step:

```
sudo cat /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
```

Which gives me something like :

```
# Automatically generated for Debian scripts. DO NOT TOUCH!
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = debian-sys-maint
password = xXxXxXxXxXxX
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysql_upgrade]
host     = localhost
user     = debian-sys-maint
password = xXxXxXxXxXxX
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
basedir  = /usr
```

Then i did

```
mysql -u root -p
```

And finally

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'xXxXxXxXxXxX' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

This should have work but i'm getting another error here :

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: NO)
```

Actually, i made some mistake before that, running this: DELETE * FROM mysq.user WHERE host = 'localhost'.

I now have only one user left, and it seems he doesn't have the permission to GRANT anything:

```
mysql> select Host, user from mysql.user;
+------------------+--------------+
| Host             | user         |
+------------------+--------------+
| %                | root         |
+------------------+--------------+
1 rows in set (0.00 sec
```

Is there a way to handle this ? Actually i just want to remove mysql server and install it again from scratch. But it will fails removing until i can first stop mysqld:

~$ ps aux | grep mysql | grep -v grep

```
root      8252  0.0  0.0  12720  2776 pts/1    Ss+  09:42   0:00 /usr/bin/dpkg --status-fd 17 --configure mysql-common:all libmysqlclient18:amd64 libdbd-mysql-perl:amd64 mysql-client-5.5:amd64 mysql-server-core-5.5:amd64 mysql-server-5.5:amd64
root      8255  0.0  0.3  61372 14180 pts/1    S+   09:42   0:00 /usr/bin/perl -w /usr/share/debconf/frontend /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.5.postinst configure 5.5.38-0+wheezy1
root      8265  0.0  0.0  10900  1676 pts/1    S+   09:42   0:00 /bin/bash /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.5.postinst configure 5.5.38-0+wheezy1
root      8579  0.0  0.0  21656  2928 pts/1    S+   09:50   0:00 whiptail --backtitle Configuration package tools --title mysql-server-5.5 Configuration --output-fd 11 --nocancel --msgbox Impossible to change « root » password of MySQL 13 198
root     30566  0.0  0.0   4180   728 ?        S    00:41   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysql    30882  0.0  1.9 368500 77668 ?        Sl   00:41   0:16 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
root     30883  0.0  0.0   5588   696 ?        S    00:41   0:00 logger -t mysqld -p daemon.error
```

i already tried it with :

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql\*
```

And it seems it fails because it cannot stop mysqld in the first place

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Kill it softly first `sudo kill 30882`, if it does not help, kill it with fire `sudo kill -9 30882`, where `30882` is pid of mysql process.

Comment: Hey, thanks it worked with killing mysql process ! i didn't even thought about using this command. I was able to remove mysql server without errors, and to reinstall it in a clean way.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. I first did

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

and then

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

worked.

Comment: This may not be a solution. Most probably your MySQL server was not running when you were trying to stop it.

Comment: This does nothing for the problem.

Answer (score 2):

first you can check the mysql running process by

```
ps -ef | grep mysql
```

then get the pid file path for the mysql and delete the .pid file

```
sudo rm path/to/.pidfile
```

and then run the command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

this worked for me.